# Select a row with Max Date for set of account number

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with three columns, ACCT_NUM, EFF_DATE and ACCT_NAME. Unique keys are ACCT_NUM and EFF_DATE.

Eg Data,

`ACCT_NUM    EFF_DATE       ACCT_NAME
0000100200  2017-01-01     Account 1
0000100200  2017-03-10     Account A
0000100200  2017-08-22     Account Alpha
0000100230  2017-01-01     Account C
0000100230  2017-05-20     Account Charlie`

and more accounts.

Want to get latest account name based of Eff_date for a set of account numbers using in clause.

`select * from ACCT_MASTER where acct_num in ('0000100200', '0000100230') order by eff_date fetch 1 row only; -- but this query returns only one account`

like to get following data,

`ACCT_NUM     ACCT_NAME
0000100200    Account Alpha
0000100230    Account Charlie`

Comment: Tag your question with the databsae you are using.

Comment: This question is for DB2 Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL you can do

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
    select acct_num, max(eff_date) as dt
    from your_table
    group by acct_num
) t2 on t1.acct_num = t2.acct_num
    and t1.eff_date = t2.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select am.*
from (select am.*,
             row_number() over (partition by acct_num order by eff_date desc) as seqnum
      from ACCT_MASTER am
      where acct_num in ('0000100200', '0000100230') 
     ) am
where seqnum = 1
order by eff_date
fetch 1 row only
```

Comment: Surprising that you didn't choose this answer.  It should be much more efficient than aggregating and joining.